# Get column names for each updated items in Radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I'm using C# 4 and ASP.Net. I'm using Telerik at version 2012.1.228.40.

I generate dynamically column names while building my datasource and I would like to get this column name back when the user updates a row.

```
protected void radGridTranslation_ItemCommand(object _sender, GridCommandEventArgs _event)
{
    if (_event.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem l_dataItem = (GridDataItem)_event.Item;
        string l_sColumnName = ... ? ...
    }
}
```

*Edit (after hutchonoid post) : I don't want to know the column names in my code behind. They need to be dynamically built from a database query. Therefore, I cannot use properties such as `UniqueName`.*

Any idea how I would do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that worked :

```
protected void radGridTranslation_ItemCommand(object _sender, GridCommandEventArgs _event)
{
    if (_event.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        if (_event.CommandName == myRadGrid.UpdateCommandName)
        {
            GridDataItem l_dataItem = (GridDataItem)_event.Item;
            Dictionary<string, string> l_gridUpdatedItemList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            l_dataItem.ExtractValues(l_gridUpdatedItemList);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> l_updatedItemWithColumn in l_gridUpdatedItemList)
            {
                // Key = The column name
                // Value = The cell value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone else !